Extract from string multiple different Texts labels that are located in various positions

I have a column call Labels, the labels are text within a string and they are located at various positions, left, mid, right the Labels (Text) ie. LGW, DUX, IAD, SPX
I want to extract from the string just the Labels (Text) which matches the LGW, DUX, IAD, SPX and leave only that part of the string in place
The labels (Text) will not always be in the same position, for example LGW will not always be in the Left position it may be in any position and will change from cell to cell within the column
I am trying to achieve what is in the second column with a formula that I could copy all the way down a list of over 200 rows
I have tried using the following formula to return one of the values, but am struggling to return multiple value
enter image description here
This is a sample of how the data is drawn into a excel spreadsheet
I then need to sort the spreadsheet out, the spreadsheet is formatted as a table so I would usually use this to sort different columns to extract the data I needed
How the spreadsheet looks once its been brought in from a ticketing software
This is the sheet I will use to sort out the data
Could not get this Formula to work

Post few sample data and then show your desired output. Post a screenshot to clarify it.

Try: =MAP(A2:A9,LAMBDA(a, LET(b, TEXTSPLIT(a,"."), c, LEN(b)=3, d, ISERR(-b), FILTER(b,d*c,""))))

I tried Mayukh formula but couldnt get it to work and kept getting a "NAME" error

With BYROW and TEXTJOIN : =TEXTJOIN("",TRUE,BYROW({"LGW";"DUX";......},LAMBDA(x,Your formula))). In your formula replace the hardcoded label with the x variable.

Ive never used the Lambda function, so this is a bit beyond my excel proficiency and would prefer to achieve the outcome with a longer formula , as I would only ever be looking for a maximum of 10 different values

@213 Do your three letter codes come from a defined list? Or can they be any three-letter capitalized code? Also, what version of Excel? And is it Windows or Mac?

The “LGW, LHR, DUX, SPX” and a few more come from stripping data from ticket information. It comes in the form of a large excel spreadsheet, that I need to extract specific data from - one of the columns is called labels and with this column is the “LGW” etc and I need to extract just the “LGW” etc so it is more easy to sort and sift the data so I can then produce pivot tables and totals from it

=IFERROR(MID(A1,FIND("LGW",A1),3), "'')
This formula worked for just 1 x value , I’m struggling to expand this out to multiple values

I thought your question was how to strip that data from your Labels columns. Where are you getting the LGW and other three letter codes that you are looking for? Are they in a single column someplace? or something else?

@213 You can expand your formula by using an array for find_text and appending a concatenated string to within_text. eg: =MID(A2,MIN(FIND({"LGW";"DUX";"IAD";"SPX";"LHR"},A2 & "LGWDUXIADSPXLHR")),3) but this begs the question of how you are deriving those three letter abbreviations. Also this method does not differentiate, for example, ABC from ABCd or ABCD. There are better methods, depending on where you have your list of valid three letter codes and what version of Excel you are using. But you seem unwilling to answer those questions.

Office Professional Plus 2021

I dont have a list of the 3 letter values, there is only LGW, LHR, DUX, SPX, IAD

@ron rosenfeld, I couldnt get your formula to work, I have attached a picture with a smaller version of your formula and to answer a previous Q, the LGW etc are airport codes - I could have another sheet with those codes if needed

@213 Looks to me to be working. It is referring to F2 and returning LGW. What did you expect?

In G5 I was expecting it return the airport code of DUX

I have managed to get your formula to work in G5, returning DUX - thank you

@213 Then you have to refer to F5. If you enter the F2 formula in G2 and fill down, the F2 will adjust to the relevant row. But you can't just enter a formula in G5 that refers to F2 and expect it to change automagically.

If there was ever a need to that I need to add an additional bit to the formula to say return all of the above and then say a 4 x value (eg NASA) - would this be possible

Since your office version is Windows, I would be using a different approach. Too long to outline in comments.

@ron - ok - thank you for your time

@213 Suggest you either post a new question with all the information you have provided here, or wait to see if this question gets re-opened.

It appears that your data includes a dot-separated three letter capitalized string which needs to be extracted.
That being the case, if you don't have a separate list of all the airport codes, you can use the following formula which should work in Office 2021:
=IFERROR(
    FILTERXML(
        "<t><s>" & SUBSTITUTE(A2, ".", "</s><s>") & "</s></t>",
        "//s[string-length()=3 and translate(.,'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz','ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ')=.]"
    ),
    ""
)


In your comments, you asked about possible four letter codes. You can modify the xpath argument in the formula to also allow four letter codes:
=IFERROR(
    FILTERXML(
        "<t><s>" & SUBSTITUTE(A2, ".", "</s><s>") & "</s></t>",
        "//s[(string-length()=3 or string-length()=4) and translate(.,'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz','ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ')=.]"
    ),
    ""
)

The xml argument forms the xml from the original stringSee XML Path Language (XPath)Version 1.0 for information about the xpath arguments.
